# What include first if I want to comply IWYU(Include-What-You-Use) in Unreal Engine 4?

Tags: c++, unreal-4, unreal, build-process

I read this article. https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Programming/UnrealBuildSystem/IWYUReferenceGuide/index.html

It says "IWYU mode is enabled by default for the Engine and Engine plugins." So, I turned on IWYU mode by adding PCHUsage = PCHUsageMode.UseExplicitOrSharedPCHs; to my module. It makes a lot of errors because of ".cpp files include their matching .h files first."

So, my question is,

- if some cpp files shares one header files(ex. one header file defines API and several cpp files have implementation), what header file should I include first?
- Some Unreal engine file like 'AutomationCommandline.cpp' include "CoreMinimal.h" first. It looks like being against the IWYU rules. If it is, how it can be compiled without error?

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps your issue is somewhere else. Only stating that you get a lot of errors because ".cpp files include their matching .h files first." does not help us help you. If you're included your files correctly, this should not be an issue.  _"if some cpp files shares one header files(ex. one header file defines API and several cpp files have implementation), what header file should I include first"_ Are you suggesting that you have something other that 1:1 match between headers and cpp files?

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt or more specifically: "Every .cpp file has a .h file of the same base name, that is the first #include in the .cpp"